# Cannot install mcrypt via homebrew OSX Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, mcrypt

Running OSX 10.10.1. I installed homebrew, and then tried running the following command:

```
brew install mcrypt
```

After which, it went through a long process of downloading/installing files. It then gave me an error:

```
checking for mhash_keygen in -lmhash... no
configure: error: "You need at least libmhash 0.8.15 to compile this program.     
http://mhash.sf.net/"
```

Running php -v in terminal:

```
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2014 09:34:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

Any help is appreciated. Everything seems to be breaking in OSX Yosemite...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue and uninstalling / reinstalling mhash resolved the issue:

```
brew uninstall mhash

brew install mhash
```

After I did this I was able to properly install mcrypt.

Comment: Even after `brew uninstall mhash` gave `Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar`, `brew install mhash` worked.  Thank you!